# How to return empty numpy array as np.ndarray([[[]]])

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a program that retrieves image and return the RGB image as 3D `np.ndarray`. I want to return  `np.ndarray([[[]]])` when image is not available.

Can we do it?

Comment: you can just return `np.array([])`

Comment: I think a more accurate one is: `return np.array([[[]]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.empty`

Which returns a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.

```
import numpy as np
empty_array = np.empty((1, 1, 1))
empty_array
```

```
array([[[5.e-324]]])
```

OR

```
import numpy as np
empty_array = np.empty((1, 1, 0))
empty_array
```

```
array([], shape=(1, 1, 0), dtype=float64)
```

which is basically

```
np.array([[[]]])
```

[DOCS](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) for more help

Comment: The second part nails it. The first half is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

simply return `np.empty((10,10,10),object)` because `x=np.empty((10,10,10))` returns array with random values already stored in the memory buffer . `x=np.empty((10,10,10),object)` will return array with `none` values.

Here (10,10,10) dimension is just for example. Use the dimensions favourable for you.

Comment: `np.full(shape=(1,1,1),fill_value=None)` is also a good alternative to get array with none values

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to make such an array:

```
In [128]: arr = np.array([[[]]])                                                                     
In [129]: arr                                                                                        
Out[129]: array([], shape=(1, 1, 0), dtype=float64)
```

You could also use `np.zeros((1,1,0))` (or `empty`); but it's no easier than [128].

But how are you going to use or test this?  I suppose you could check:

```
In [130]: arr.nbytes                                                                                 
Out[130]: 0
```

I believe one of the image packages (`cv2`?) returns `None` if it can't load the image.  Testing for `None` is easy, reliable, and widely used in python.

```
In [131]: arr = None                                                                                 
In [132]: arr is None                                                                                
Out[132]: True
```

It might make more sent to use a 'image' with 0 size, but still the full 3 color channels, `np.zeros((0,0,3), np.int8)`.